# Why scala serializability differs in case classes with same constructor parameter types?

Tags: scala, generics, serialization, scala-generics

Why am I able to serialize this:

```
// Serialize: OK
case class ClassWithType2[T:TypeTag](x:T)  {
  val tpe:java.lang.reflect.Type = Util.toJavaClass[T]
}
```

... but not this

```
class TypeAware[T:TypeTag]() {
  val tpe:java.lang.reflect.Type = Util.toJavaClass[T]
}

// Serialize: FAIL.
// No valid constructor for ClassWithType1
// in: java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize
case class ClassWithType1[T:TypeTag](x:T) extends TypeAware[T]
```

Both seem have the same constructor type prototype:

```
[T:TypeTag](x:T)
```

and both extend scala.Serializable and java.io.Serializable

```
val s1:Serializable = ClassWithType1(x=123)
val s2:Serializable = ClassWithType2(x=123)
val s3:java.io.Serializable = ClassWithType1(x=123)
val s4:java.io.Serializable = ClassWithType2(x=123)
```

Its there a way to implement TypeAware subclasses that:

- avoid having to declare tpe in every subclass (as ClassWithType2 does)?
- allows the object to be serialized

Here's the test harness

```
class TypesTest {

  @Test
  def serializeTypeTest(): Unit = {
    val obj2:Object = ClassWithType2(x=123)
    Util.copyBySerialization(obj2)  // Success!

    val obj1:Object = ClassWithType1(x=123)
    Util.copyBySerialization(obj1) // Fail
  }
}

object Util {
  def toJavaClass[T:TypeTag]: Class[_] = {
    val tpe = typeOf[T]
    runtimeMirror(tpe.getClass.getClassLoader).runtimeClass(tpe.typeSymbol.asClass)
  }

  def copyBySerialization[T](obj: T): T = deserialize(serialize(obj))

  def serialize[T](obj: T): Array[Byte] = {
    val byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut)
    objOut.writeObject(obj)
    objOut.close()
    byteOut.close()
    byteOut.toByteArray
  }

  def deserialize[T](bytes: Array[Byte]): T = {
    val byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    val objIn = new ObjectInputStream(byteIn)
    val obj = objIn.readObject().asInstanceOf[T]
    byteIn.close()
    objIn.close()
    obj
  }

}
```

Comment: TypeAware doesn't extends java.io.Serializable.

Comment: Why would it be required to? I'm asking to serialize ClassWithType1, which claims to be Serializable.
NB. The serialization fails because it can't find a constructor for ClassWithType1, not because TypeAware or its members can't be serialized (serializing the java.reflect.Type works fine).

Comment: Every few years, I try to refresh my memory about Java serialization, but I don't think today is the day. But see my answer; the ctor is not nullary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just quoting the Javadoc:

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the
>   subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state
>   of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package
>   fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class
>   it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the
>   class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this
>   is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.

The ctor for TypeAware includes the implicit parameter.

Edit: one idea is to make the type tag a member. Or similar. It doesn't save as much syntax.

```
abstract class TypeAware {
  protected def tt: TypeTag[_]
  def tpe:java.lang.reflect.Type = Util.toJavaClass(tt)
}

case class ClassWithType1[T](x:T)(implicit val tt: TypeTag[T]) extends TypeAware
```

Edit, more linx:

[tech page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html)

[faq](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/serializationfaq-jsp-136699.html)

[your question](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/serializationfaq-jsp-136699.html#serialsuper)

Comment: So it seems that making TypeAware extends Serializable fixes this by adding a missing constructor to its subclass. Not very intuitive, but I'll take it.

Comment: I guess it's worth reading the docs if you have to use it. There's also a faq entry about the decision to require the marker trait.